# assignment to char from char * makes integer from pointer without a case

Tags: c, char, assignment-operator, string-literals, incompatibletypeerror

I need to make a program that calculates and grades any number of students based on the inputs. I also need to print the top 3 students after it is graded and display the final grade in Letter format. I was wondering what I did wrong in the Letter grade because this kept popping as an error: [Error for letter grade](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LqfZG.png)

Here is my code so far:

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct student {
    char firstName[50], lastName[50], equigrade;
    int q1, q2, q3, q4, q5, midterms, finals;
    float FinalGrade;
} s[15];

int main() {
    int i, n, q1, q2, q3, q4, q5, midterms, finals, TotalQuiz;
    float QuizGrade, MidtermExamGrade, FinalExamGrade, FinalGrade;
    printf("Enter number of students:");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    printf("\nENTER STUDENT'S INFORMATION\n");

// storing information
for (i = 0; i < n; ++i) 
{
    printf("\nEnter Student's Full Name: ");
    scanf("%s %s", s[i].firstName, s[i].lastName);
    printf("SCORES\n");
    printf("Quiz 1: ");
    scanf("%d", &s[i].q1);
    printf("Quiz 2: ");
    scanf("%d", &s[i].q2);
    printf("Quiz 3: ");
    scanf("%d", &s[i].q3);
    printf("Quiz 4: ");
    scanf("%d", &s[i].q4);
    printf("Quiz 5: ");
    scanf("%d", &s[i].q5);
    printf("Midterms (100pts): ");
    scanf("%d", &s[i].midterms);
    printf("Finals (100pts): ");
    scanf("%d", &s[i].finals);
    printf("\n");
}

//calculation
TotalQuiz = q1 + q2 +  q3 + q4 + q5;

QuizGrade = (TotalQuiz/50)*100*0.50;
MidtermExamGrade = (midterms/100)*100*0.20;
FinalExamGrade = (finals/100)*100*0.30;
FinalGrade = QuizGrade + MidtermExamGrade + FinalExamGrade;

// alphabetic equivalent
for(i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    if(s[i].FinalGrade>=97 && s[i].FinalGrade<=100)
    {
        s[i].equigrade = "A+";
    }
    else if(s[i].FinalGrade>=93 && s[i].FinalGrade<=96)
    {
        s[i].equigrade = 'A';
    }
    else if(s[i].FinalGrade>=90 && s[i].FinalGrade<=92)
    {
        s[i].equigrade = "A-";
    }
    else if(s[i].FinalGrade>=87 && s[i].FinalGrade<=89)
    {
        s[i].equigrade = "B+";
    }
    else if(s[i].FinalGrade>=83 && s[i].FinalGrade<=86)
    {
        s[i].equigrade = 'B';
    }
    else if(s[i].FinalGrade>=80 && s[i].FinalGrade<=82)
    {
        s[i].equigrade = "B-";
    }
    else if(s[i].FinalGrade>=77 && s[i].FinalGrade<=79)
    {
        s[i].equigrade = "C+";
    }
    else if(s[i].FinalGrade>=73 && s[i].FinalGrade<=76)
    {
        s[i].equigrade = 'C';
    }
    else if(s[i].FinalGrade>=70 && s[i].FinalGrade<=72)
    {
        s[i].equigrade = "C-";
    }
}


printf("Displaying Information:\n\n");

// displaying information
for (i = 0; i < n; ++i) 
{
    printf("First name: %s %s\n", s[i].firstName, s[i].lastName);
    printf("Marks: %d\n", s[i].q1);
    printf("Marks: %d\n", s[i].q2);
    printf("Marks: %d\n", s[i].q3);
    printf("Marks: %d\n", s[i].q4);
    printf("Marks: %d\n", s[i].q5);
    printf("\n");
}
return 0;
```

}

Comment: Don't post pictires of text, post text as properly formattd text. Your error log is txt.

Answer (score 1):

According to the declaration

```
char firstName[50], lastName[50], equigrade;
```

the data member `equigrade` has the type `char`. But in statements like this

```
s[i].equigrade = "A+";
```

you are trying to assign a pointer to a string literal to a character. That is the string literal `"A+"` has the character array type `char[3]` that used as an initializer is converted to a pointer to its first element of the type `char *`.

Redeclare the variable like a pointer

```
char firstName[50], lastName[50], *equigrade;
```

And everywhere in such statements use string literals instead of integer character constants. That is instead of for example this assignment

```
s[i].equigrade = 'A';
```

write

```
s[i].equigrade = "A";
```

Pay attention to that in these statements

```
QuizGrade = (TotalQuiz/50)*100*0.50;
MidtermExamGrade = (midterms/100)*100*0.20;
FinalExamGrade = (finals/100)*100*0.30;
```

it seems you need to use the floating arithmetic in each sub-expression. That is write

```
QuizGrade = (TotalQuiz/50.0f)*100*0.50f;
MidtermExamGrade = (midterms/100.0f)*100*0.20f;
FinalExamGrade = (finals/100,0f)*100*0.30f;
```

Also in this statement

```
TotalQuiz = q1 + q2 +  q3 + q4 + q5;
```

you are using uninitialized variables q1, q2, q3, q4, q5. This statement does not make a sense. Maybe you mean using data members of the structure q1, q2, q3, q4, q5.

I do not know but maybe you want in the for loop ro write

```
for (i = 0; i < n; ++i) 
{
      printf("Quiz 1: ");
      scanf("%d", &s[i].q1

      q1 = s[i].q1;

     // and so on
);
```

Comment: i did as you said and the error is thankfully gone. but in the printing, equigrade only outputs (null).  Is there anything wrong with the computation?

Comment: @ssjwi_ See the bottom of my answer.

Comment: @ssjwi_ Where are you outputting equigrade?  To output it you need to use the conversion specifier %s.

Comment: it still displays (null) despite changing it to floating arithmetic.

Comment: @ssjwi_ It is because this statement TotalQuiz = q1 + q2 +  q3 + q4 + q5; does not make a sense. You are using uninitialized variables q1, q2, q3, q4, q5.

Comment: @ssjwi_ Investigate your program. Check How  the variables q1, q2, q3, q4, and q5 should be used.